# ¿Cómo realizar solicitud a propietario del recurso con JavaScript & Ajax?

Tags: javascript, ajax

Estoy haciendo una solicitud a un propietario del recurso, pero al ejecutarla me devuelve por consola:

Ha fallado la carga del script con origen "https://api.comprobanteselectronicos.go.cr/recepcion-sandbox/v1/&callback=jQuery31109684584746948414_1510257777262?_=1510257777263"

Creo que jQuery31109684584746948414_1510257777262?_=1510257777263  o parte de esta cadena es el código que necesito para usarlo como grant_type para obtener luego un Token de autentificación si es así

¿Cómo puedo asignar este código a una variable desde JavaScript?

Esta es mi Funcion:

```
  function ObtenerAutorizacionCode() {
            var accessToken = undefined;
            // xhr.send()
            $.ajax({
                method: "GET",
                url: "https://api.comprobanteselectronicos.go.cr/recepcion-sandbox/v1/&callback=?",
                contentType: "text/html",
                dataType: "json"
            })

        }
```

Comment: Creo que tendrías que hacer una llamada JSONP y no la estás haciendo bien, con lo que no obtienes los datos que pediste

Answer (score 1):

no puedes realizar llamadas con AJAX recursos alojados en otros dominios por seguridad.
Hay una alternativa, se llama JSONP, lo puedes revisar en esta pagina:
http://web.ontuts.com/tutoriales/jsonp-llamadas-ajax-entre-dominios/

Sino lo puedes hacer de esta manera, lo que yo hago es crear un recurso en mi dominio y accedo mediante ella, por ejemplo puedes revisar esta pagina:
https://www.adictosaltrabajo.com/tutoriales/cross-domain-jquery/

Saludos